# Colour Laser MFP

Tags: linux, printer

I am in the market for a colour laser multifunction printer.  I have the following requirements:

- Ethernet networking (RJ-45)
- Duplex printing and scanning
- Document feeder for scanning
- Scanning and printing should be able to be initiated over network.
- Good Linux compatibility

In terms of budget I would be looking ideally at less than £300.  I would consider a recommendation for a unit that would be a good fit that is available secondhand.

Comment: Just to clarify...you want someone **away** from the scanner to initiate a scan job remotely rather than have the scanner sent it via email or shared folder?  I ask because for us, this has never been a reliable workflow and ended up getting a desktop scanner.

Comment: In reality no thinking about it I don't need that functionality, that's an extension of my current workflow, using a desktop scanner.  Scan to share or email would be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some digging around and in the end I got a [Lexmark CX 310](http://media.lexmark.com/www/doc/en_US/Lexmark-CX310.pdf).  The only thing it falls down on is the duplex scanning automatically, however the interface allows for it.

Having used it for a while now its a good little printer and fits nicely to my needs.